# can i make php calles without needing http web sever (in local client application)

Tags: php, function, local

Is there away to invoke php functions with needing the all web server thing ?
i like to invoke php function on my local pc without opening port ? and running server

Comment: You probably wanted to say: "_without_ needing the all web server thing"

Answer (score 3):

You can run PHP from the command line, or use something like [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) for a GUI.

Comment: Note that PHP is not especially useful for multithreaded programming, so even if it is possible to do simple GTK programs it's not so good when it comes to performance and user experience. PHP is not suited for that kind of GUI programming. It is however very useful for doing simple shell scripts and such.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing

ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

windows:

```
http://www.wampserver.com/en/
```

mac:

```
http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html
```

### Tutorials

- http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-command-line-1